# Adding a headline only if none is set already

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to add a headline to a list that shows the date. It works but only if there are'nt **multiple dates** of the same. Each *date headline* should only be shown once.

Example - current problem:

```
01.02.2019
- XY
05.03.2019
- ABC
05.03.2019
- DEF
05.03.2019
- FOO
```

It should be like this:

```
01.02.2019
- XY
05.03.2019
- ABC
- DEF
- FOO
```

This is the code I'm using to check id the date is today:

```
HTML:
<template v-for="(meetup, index) in filteredItems">
    <v-subheader v-if="checkIsToday(meetup.date)" inset>
        <span v-if="todaySubheader === false">TODAY</span>
    </v-subheader>
```

JS:

```
data() {
        return {
            todaySubheader: false,
            [...]
            checkIsToday(val) {
                if (val && this.todaySubheader === false) {
                    this.todaySubheader = true
                }
                return isToday(new Date(val))
            },
```

How to avoid adding a second headline after one is already set?

(I'm using VueJS with the Vuetify framework)

Comment: Can you provide your real code or a demo? because this is not  going to display a thing

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide your full code, so I don't know how your Objects look like.

One possible solution could be grouping your items by date in a Vue Computed function.

```js
const groupBy = key => array =>
  array.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(obj);
    return objectsByKeyValue;
  }, {});

const items = [
  { name: 'XY', date: '01.02.2019' },
  { name: 'DEF', date: '05.03.2019' },
  { name: 'ABC', date: '05.03.2019' },
  { name: 'FOO', date: '05.03.2019' }
];

const groupByDate = groupBy('date');

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(groupByDate(items), null, 2)
);
```

Add this code to a computed Vue Function:
[Vue computed documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)